# Why Didn't the Energy-Momentum Relation Work?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, momentum, mass-energy, speed

I am currently studying for the [GRE Physics subject test](https://www.ets.org/gre/subject/about/content/physics) by working through published past tests. My question is about problem 20 from the test [GR8677](https://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/undergrad/greStuff/exam_GR8677.pdf):

> 20. A positive kaon ($K^{{}+{}}$) has a rest mass of $494\, {\rm MeV}/c^2$, whereas a proton has a rest mass of  $938\, {\rm MeV}/c^2$. If a kaon has a total energy that is equal to the proton rest energy, the speed of the kaon is most nearly
>
> (A) $0.25\, c$
>
> (B) $0.40\, c$
>
> (C) $0.55\, c$
>
> (D) $0.70\, c$
>
> (E) $0.85\, c$

The solution (readily available [online](http://grephysics.net/ans/8677/20)) is to solve the equation $$\gamma\, m_{\rm kaon}c^2 = m_{\rm proton}c^2$$ for $\gamma$ and then to solve $$\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\beta^2}}$$ for $\beta$. This can be worked out to give the correct answer, (E). This I understand.

My first thought when encountering this problem, however, was to instead use the energy-momentum relation $$E^2 = (pc)^2 + (mc^2)^2$$ to solve the problem. We are given the total energy of the kaon and its mass, so I solved for $p$: $$p = \sqrt{E^2 - (mc^2)^2} / c$$ $$= \sqrt{(938)^2 - (494)^2}\, {\rm MeV} / c$$ $$\approx \sqrt{(900)^2 - (500)^2}\, {\rm MeV} / c$$ $$\approx 800\, {\rm MeV} / c$$ The velocity would then be $$v = \frac{p}{m} = \frac{800\, {\rm MeV} / c}{494\, {\rm MeV} / c^2} \approx \frac{8}{5} c = 1.6c$$ which obviously can't be right because the speed of the kaon can't be larger than $c$. However, I have done this problem several times so I don't think I have made an algebraic error.

My question is then **what, specifically, is wrong with my approach**? It's clearly not the most efficient tactic, but I don't want to know the best way to solve a problem like this. Rather, I would like to improve my understanding of SR.

Comment: Could the user who downvoted please explain why they did so and how to improve the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the nonrelativistic approximation for the momentum-velocity relation. Use the one including the gamma and you will get correct values

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the relativistic expression for the momentum:

$$ p = \gamma m v = \frac{mv}{\sqrt{1 - v^2/c^2}} $$

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, this option would have worked except for the mistake at the end. You used the relationship p=mv, which is a non-relativistic relationship. Instead, using the relativistic momentum relationship would give you the right answer, provided that you can properly isolate velocity. It would most likely be easier to use the first relationship between mass and energy to solve for velocity.